# How to install java and kotlin on a macbook to build apache calcite

Tags: install, homebrew, java

I want to build Apache calcite on my MacBookPro (and possibly extend it).  I have installed Java (1.8.0_311 from the Oracle site, or at least java -version claims I got that right) and installed Kotlin (1.6.10 by `brew install kotlin`).  However, I obviously don't have things installed correctly or some other error, because when I try to follow the instructions for building calcite 1.29 (typing `./gradelw build`), what I get as errors are:

```
> Task :buildSrc:Tmp:compileKotlin FAILED
> Task :buildSrc:javac:compileKotlin FAILED
> Task :buildSrc:buildext:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-------------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed with an exception.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tooks in the Java Installation.  Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.
```

Comment: Not a mac user but try `brew install java` if you haven't got a JDK installed. If that doesn't work then uninstall any JREs that are installed separately from the JDK.

Comment: What exact link did you use from Oracle. (They have messed up macOS naming re JRE).  Was it a full JDK as your error message suggests it is not. Also why such an old version of Java?